# dlsym()'ing a global variable in C++

Tags: c++, linux, g++, shared-libraries

I want to make a program which is able to `dlopen()` a series of libraries (written by myself) and run all the functions stored in a global variable called `test_suite` inside that .so file, which is a NULL-terminated array of function pointers (the functions' signatures are predefined by myself, no need to worry about that).

The problem is g++ mangles that variable. The library is compiled as:

```
g++ -Wall -shared -rdynamic -fPIC foo.cpp -o foo.so
```

and the "function index" is declared and allocated statically as:

```
const testunit_testcase test_suite = { ... }
```

yet

```
objdump -t foo.so  | grep test_suite
```

shows:

```
0000000000200940 l     O .data.rel.ro   0000000000000020              _ZL10test_suite
```

What I need is

```
0000000000200940 l     O .data.rel.ro   0000000000000020              test_suite
```

So I can `dlsym(dlh, "test_suite")` in the program `dlopen()`'ing  `foo.so`

Thanks

---

**Addendum**

Yes, `extern "C"` was the first thing I've tried:

```
extern "C" {
        const testunit_testcase test_suite[] = { 
                //TESTUNIT_DEF_TESTCASE(doTest),
                {NULL, NULL},
        };  
}
```

I am using:

> **g++ -v** Using built-in specs.
>   COLLECT_GCC=g++
>   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.5.2/lto-wrapper
>   Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
>   Configured with:
>   /build/src/**gcc-4.5-20110127**/configure
>   --prefix=/usr --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,ada
>   --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-lto --enable-plugin --enable-gold --with-plugin-ld=ld.gold --disable-multilib --disable-libstdcxx-pch --with-system-zlib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-ppl
>   --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info Thread model: posix **gcc version 4.5.2**
>   20110127 (prerelease) (GCC)

---

**Addendum 2**

For whatever reasons

```
extern "C" {
     const testunit_testcase test_suite = { ... }
}
```

does **not** work, BUT this one does:

```
extern "C" const testunit_testcase test_suite = { ... }
```

**My question now**: As I can see in some of your answers, enclosing `extern "C" { ... }` works for you. Are there any compiler flags I could use to make sure that `test_suite` will never be mangled, no matter what 4.x (at least) g++ version is used?

Comment: 1. Why are you making it `static` if you want it to be used by something outside the library? 2. Is the mangled name what you get even with `extern "C"`?

Comment: Yes, I get it mangled though I have extern "C". Sorry about the "static", it was left over after I tried without it and I was still getting it mangled.

Comment: If it's still mangled after extern "C", it's not being rebuilt, or you have the same symbol defined elsewhere

Comment: @nos: or as you can see in "addendum 2" of the question, `extern "C" { foo }` is not the same as `extern "C" foo`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem isn't one of name mangling.  (Or probably isn't: public
variable names are not usually mangled.)  The real problem is that the
"const" means implicit static, rendering the variable invisible outside
the translation unit.  To avoid this, the variable must be explicitly
declared extern.  And "The form of linkage-specification that contains
a brace-enclosed declaration-seq does not affect whether the contained
declarations are definitions or not (3.1); the form of
linkage-specification directly containing a single declaration is
treated as an extern specifier (7.1.1) for the purpose of determining
whether the contained declaration is a definition."  Which, while it
doesn't seem to address your issue directly (the presence of an
initializer ensures that the declaration is a definition), it does seem
to indicate the intent: within a brace enclosed linkage specifier, the
usual rules apply; if the linkage specifier applies directly to the
declaration, it's as if the declaration were explicitly extern.  So you
can write either:

```
extern "C" {
    testunit_testcase const test_suite[] // ...
}
```

or

```
extern "C" testunit_testcase const test_suite[] // ...
```

But there must be an extern which applies explicitly to the definition,
in order to override the implicit "static" of "const".

Comment: Thanks for pointing out why the block didn't "count". I wasn't happy with the amount of handwaving in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This

x.cxx:

```
 extern "C"
 {
    extern const int test_suite[] = { 0 };
 }
```

works for me:

```
~/ec% g++ -Wall -rdynamic -shared x.cxx -o x.so
~/ec% objdump -t x.so | grep test_suite
00000444 g     O .rodata        00000004              test_suite
```

If I don't `extern` `test_suite` it doesn't get exported at all. This makes sense as const at file or namespace scope implies `static`. It doesn't make sense because I would expect the `extern "C"` block to "count" for that. I don't know if this is a gcc bug or not. Can you reduce your problem to something similar in size?

Comment: Oh I've just edited my question with the same observation you just did. So yes, I was able to reproduce it. What version of g++ are you using?

Comment: gcc version 4.3.2 (Debian 4.3.2-1.1)

Comment: getting rid of the `const` and by extension the implicit `static` also works (with just the extern "C" {}).

Answer (score 0):

You're using a C++ compiler, so the name gets mangled. Try using either `gcc` (if possible) or  use

```
extern "C" {
     const testunit_testcase test_suite = { ... }
}
```

The `extern "C"` deactivates the name mangling.

Answer (score -1):

Don't make that variable `static`.

`static` means that the variable is local to the current compilation unit, that's why g++ modifies its name. If you want the variable to be accessible "from the outside" you shouldn't make it `static`. So, in the .cpp file, define the variable like this:

```
const testunit_testcase test_suite = { ... }
```

If you also declare the variable in a corresponding .h file, make that declaration `extern`:

```
extern const testunit_testcase test_suite;
```

Comment: That's how it's defined, only as `const`. That has been edited in my question. The problem persists.

Comment: @Flavius: For me `objdump` shows an unmodified `test_suite` symbol name if the variable is not declared as `static`, and `_ZL10test_suite` if it *is* `static`.

Comment: Are you using the same version of g++? I've done it exactly as you can see in the current state of the question. I've also tested it with `nm` - the name is mangled. `dlsym(dlh, "test_suite")` returns `NULL` too.

Comment: @Flavius: I haven't tried that snapshot you use, but have tried the versions I have installed (v4.4.5 and v4.5.1). Also I haven't used your type `test_suite` but a custom struct, but I don't think that would make a difference.